# Как использовать Django 2.2 с legacy базой данных PostgreSQL 8.4?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

Разрабатываю новое приложение на Django (DRF+Angular). На данный момент актуальная LTS версия Django 2.2. Необходимые данные хранятся в базе данных PostgreSQL 8.4. Но Django 2.2 поддерживает PostgreSQL 9.4 и выше. Как поступить в данной ситуации? Обновить PostgreSQL нет возможности.

Comment: Видимо, придётся брать старую версию libpq, брать старую версию psycopg2 и переделывать код Django 2.2 чтобы научить её работать со старыми версиями

Comment: Перейти на MySQL или SQLite тоже не вариант?

Comment: @andreymal Боюсь, с моим уровнем знаний и навыков это будет крайне затруднительно, переделывать код Django. А что Вы думаете на счет такого варианта: написать прослойку для работы с БД на Django 1.9 (уже не поддерживается разработчиками, но поддерживает PostgreSQL 8.4). А к ней обращаться как к API из приложения на Django 2.2. Какие могут быть трудности, подводные камни?

Comment: @Assur Не вариант.